# Amazon elastic compute cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created an ubuntu 32 bit instance and installed python packages on it.
My code is running fine on it.
Now I need to create another instance exactly same as this running instance,But the main concern is that both instances shouldnot share the database or mysql.
Can I install different mysql in both or is there any other wayout?

Comment: You could put the database data on an extra EBS unit, and only clone the instance itself.

Comment: Could you clarify if you mean you want or don't want them both to share the same database? I presume you mean you do want them to share the database, in which case it would be neatest to move the database to either another ec2 instance, or create an RDS instance. RDS is awesome for a number of reasons. It allows extremely easy scheduled backups. You can roll back to an arbitrary point in time, and you can upgrade the size & type of the machine at the flick of a switch.

Comment: You can't fine-tune RDS. You can't inspect its logs.

Answer (score 0):

To launch additional EC2 instances based on one you've already created, just go to the EC2 dashboard in your account, view your instances, select the one you want to clone and from the ACTIONS menu select "Launch more like this." Your new server request will kick off and you can change any parameters you want to in that process (such as throwing your new instance into a different AZ, etc.)

For running MySQL separately, you have a couple of good/easy options here:

1. If the MySQL engine is already installed on the first server (the one you're cloning) you could run a parallel engine on your second server, so they both run in parallel -- and are entirely independent of one another.
2. Alternatively, you could spin up a MySQL flavored RDS instance and simply run two DBs on that, one for each of your two EC2 servers. That would take the MySQL overhead off of your EC2s, give you one place to manage your DBs, and would probably be less of a management hassle in the long run.